# WebStorm IDE can not connect to node --inspect application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, webstorm, remote-debugging

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  database:
    image: mongo:3.6
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin

  server:
    restart: on-failure
    image: parseplatform/parse-server:5.2.3
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
      - 9229:9229
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=$SERVER_APPLICATION_ID
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_NAME=$SERVER_APPLICATION_NAME
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=$SERVER_MASTER_KEY
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://admin:admin@mongo/parse_server?authSource=admin
      - PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_GRAPHQL=true
      - PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD=/parse-server/cloud/main.js
      - PARSE_SERVER_GRAPH_QLSCHEMA=/parse-server/cloud/schema_2.graphql
    links:
      - database:mongo
    depends_on:
      - database
    entrypoint: "node --inspect /parse-server/bin/parse-server"
    volumes:
      - ./parse-server/cloud:/parse-server/cloud
      - ./parse-server/config:/parse-server/config
      - ./parse-server/scripts:/parse-server/scripts
```

After running the `docker-compose up` I'm adding an `Attach to Node.js/Chrome` configuration like this:

[image]

Then I press the `debug` button with the hope of connecting remotely but I get this error message right after:

[image]

Also if I'm taking this link:

> Debugger listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:9229/8d1f289a-3fee-48bc-a549-57e9427e40f1
> 2023-03-17T21:06:30.486524291Z For help, see:
> https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

and using it inside a browser I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Could you check if the issue persists after upgrading to WebStorm 2022.3.4?

Comment: This issue was fixed on 2022.3.4

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I had to update the IDE to 2022.3.4.